# How to upsample a panda data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, sampling, do-loops

I have a comma separated data file as follows:

```
ID | StartTimeStamp | EndTimeStamp | Duration (in seconds) | AssetName
1233 | 2017-01-01 00:00:02 | 2017-01-01 00:10:01 | 601 | Car1
1233 | 2017-01-01 00:10:01 | 2017-01-01 00:10:12 | 11 | Car1
...
1235 | 2017-01-01 00:00:02 | 2017-01-01 00:10:01 | 601 | CarN
```

etc.

Now I would like to create the following using the starttime and duration to upsample the data.

```
ID | StartTimeStamp |  AssetName
1233 | 2017-01-01 00:00:02 | Car1
1233 | 2017-01-01 00:00:03 | Car1
1233 | 2017-01-01 00:00:04 | Car1
...
1233 | 017-01-01 00:10:01 | Car1
...
1235 | 2017-01-01 00:00:02 | CarN
1235 | 2017-01-01 00:00:03 | CarN
1235 | 2017-01-01 00:00:04 | CarN
... (i.e. 601 rows of data one per second)
1235 | 2017-01-01 00:10:01 | CarN
```

but I am add odds on how to do this as upsampling seems to be only able to work with timeseries? I was thinking of using a for loop using the `StartTimeStamp` and number of seconds in the file, but am at a loss on how to go about this?

Answer (score 2):

You can resample for each `ID` group and then fill the gaps in character columns

```
import pandas as pd

df_resampled = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.StartTimeStamp)).groupby('ID')

# Expand out the dataframe for one second
df_resampled = df_resampled.resample('1S').asfreq()

# Interpolate AssetName for each group
df_resampled['AssetName'] = df_resampled['AssetName'].ffill().bfill()
```